# Adding extra celery configs to Airflow

Tags: celery, airflow

Anyone know where I can add extra celery configs to airflow celery executor? For instance I want http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-pool-restarts this property but how do I allow extra celery properties..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the just-released Airflow 1.9.0 and this is now configurable.

In airflow.cfg there is this line:

```
# Import path for celery configuration options
celery_config_options = airflow.config_templates.default_celery.DEFAULT_CELERY_CONFIG
```

which points to a python file from the import path. The current default version can is https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/config_templates/default_celery.py

If you need a setting that isn't tweakable via that file then create a new module, say 'my_celery_config.py':

```
CELERY_CONFIG = {
    # ....
}
```

and put it in your AIRFLOW_HOME dir (i.e. along side the dags/ folder) and then set `celery_config_options = my_celery_config.CELERY_CONFIG` in the config.

Comment: expanding on your answer:
`from airflow.config_templates.default_celery import DEFAULT_CELERY_CONFIG`

`CELERY_CONFIG = dict(DEFAULT_CELERY_CONFIG, **{key1: value1, ...})`
will give you all the regular defaults, with your values overriding

Comment: This isn't working for me in the newest version of airflow

Answer (score 1):

In case you're running Airflow in Docker and you want to change the Celery configuration, you need to do the following:

1. Create an Airflow `config` folder (if you don't have one already) at the same level where your `dags` folder is and add a custom celery configuration file (e.g. `custom_celery_config.py`) there.
2. Change the default Celery configuration in the `custom_celery_config.py`. The idea is that this python script should contain a variable, which contains the default Celery configuration plus your changes to it. E.g. if you like to change the `task_queues` configuration of Celery, your `custom_celery_config.py` should look like this:

   ```
   from airflow.config_templates.default_celery import DEFAULT_CELERY_CONFIG
   from kombu import Exchange, Queue

    CELERY_TASK_QUEUES = [
        Queue('task1', Exchange('task1', type='direct'), routing_key='task1', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 8}),
        Queue('task2', Exchange('task2', type='direct'), routing_key='task2', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority': 6}),
    ]

    CELERY_CONFIG = {
        **DEFAULT_CELERY_CONFIG,
        "task_queues": CELERY_TASK_QUEUES
    }
   ```
3. Mount the `config` folder in the `docker-compose.yml`:

   ```
   volumes:
       - /data/airflow/config:/opt/airflow/config
   ```
4. Set the Celery configuration in the `docker-compose.yml` like this (since Docker can see the `config` folder, it can access your `custom_celery_config.py`):

   ```
   AIRFLOW__CELERY__CELERY_CONFIG_OPTIONS: 'custom_celery_config.CELERY_CONFIG'
   ```
5. Restart the Airflow Webserver, Scheduler etc.

Reference: [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html#built-in-pythonpath-entries-in-airflow).

For more info about the Celery configuration check [this](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html) documentation.