# How to use airflow with Celery

Tags: python, airflow

I'm new to airflow and celery, and I have finished drawing dag by now, but I want to run task in two computers which are in the same subnet, I want to know how to modify the airflow.cfg. Some examples could be better. Thanks to any answers orz.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/executor/use-celery.html) covers this quite nicely:

First, you will need a celery backend. This can be for example Redis or RabbitMQ. Then, the executor parameter in your airflow.cfg should be set to `CeleryExecutor`.

Then, in the `celery` section of the airflow.cfg, set the `broker_url` to point to your celery backend (e.g. redis://your_redis_host:your_redis_port/1).
Point `celery_result_backend` to a sql database (you can use the same as your main airflow db).

Then, on your worker machines simply kick off airflow worker and your jobs should start on the two machines.

Comment: Are the broker_url of two machines' airflow.cfg the same? I have a question that is the broker_url in airflow.cfg is this machine send tasks to and other machine to get tasks from?

Comment: The broker_url is the same for both hosts. Airflow assumes the configuration file is the same for all instances of an airflow cluster. The broker_url does not necessarily point to a host running airflow, but instead points to a celery backend (i.e. Redis or RabbitMQ)

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979811/adding-extra-celery-configs-to-airflow) to know how to set `Celery` configurations for `Airflow`

Comment: Link 404s now. Should either be updated or more context should be added to answer.

Comment: @MatthijsBrouns Does this mean that, if I have a celery configured + 3 workers, then (in the web interface) start a task, this task will run in triplicate (3 copies of the task each in a worker)?

Comment: @JonyD no each task will run only on one worker. If there are multiple tasks however which do not depend on each other they will get distributed over the 3 workers

Comment: @MatthijsBrouns - check if this is the latest version of your link ? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/celery.html