# Airflow with CeleryExecutor is not picking the configuration set for Celery from airflow.cfg

Tags: python-2.7, celery, airflow, celery-task, airflow-scheduler

I have been stuck with this issue for a while now.

I followed steps and was successful to up the celery with tasks and when I run celery alone its working as expected:

```
-------------- celery@xxxxcxxxxx.zzzz.org v4.3.0 (rhubarb)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-6.7-Santiago 2019-05-11 11:34:25
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x7fcb942e93d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@xx.xx.xx.xx:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 5 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
[tasks]
  . tasks.add
  . tasks.rehi
```

However, when I configured the same in airflow.cfg using the below:[Checkthis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129192/how-to-use-airflow-with-celery)

This is my airflow.cfg:

```
executor=CeleryExecutor

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@xx.xx.xx:5672/'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/'

# The SqlAlchemy connection string to the metadata database.
# SqlAlchemy supports many different database engine, more information
# their website
#sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////home/apservices/airflow/airflow.db
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@yy.yy.yy.yy:5432/airflow
```

However, when I run `airflow worker` Its just not picking up the configurations given in the airflow.cfg:

```
-------------- celery@xxx.xx.org v4.3.0 (rhubarb)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Linux-2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-6.7-Santiago 2019-05-11 12:00:57
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         airflow.executors.celery_executor:0x7fa16cf99750
- ** ---------- .> transport:   sqla+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
- ** ---------- .> results:     mysql://airflow:**@localhost:3306/airflow
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default
```

Complete Stacktrace:

> [2019-05-11 12:00:56,936] {configuration.py:206} WARNING - section/key
>   [celery/celery_ssl_active] not found in config [2019-05-11
>   12:00:56,936] {default_celery.py:41} WARNING - Celery Executor will
>   run without SSL [2019-05-11 12:00:56,938] {**init**.py:45} INFO -
>   Using executor CeleryExecutor
>
> -------------- celery@xx.xx.org v4.3.0 (rhubarb)
>   ---- **** -----
>   --- * ***  * -- Linux-2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-redhat-6.7-Santiago
>   2019-05-11 12:00:57
>   -- * - **** ---
>   - ** ---------- [config]
>   - ** ---------- .> app:         airflow.executors.celery_executor:0x7fa16cf99750
>   - ** ---------- .> transport:   sqla+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
>   - ** ---------- .> results:     mysql://airflow:**@localhost:3306/airflow
>   - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
>   -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
>   --- ***** -----  -------------- [queues]
>                   .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default
>
> [2019-05-11 12:00:57,160: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error:
>   TypeError("Invalid argument(s) 'visibility_timeout' sent to
>   create_engine(), using configuration
>   MySQLDialect_mysqldb/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword
>   arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.",)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py",
>   line 205, in start
>       self.blueprint.start(self)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py",
>   line 119, in start
>       step.start(parent)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py",
>   line 369, in start
>       return self.obj.start()   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 318, in start
>       blueprint.start(self)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py",
>   line 119, in start
>       step.start(parent)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/tasks.py",
>   line 41, in start
>       c.connection, on_decode_error=c.on_decode_error,   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py",
>   line 297, in TaskConsumer
>       **kw   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py",
>   line 386, in **init**
>       self.revive(self.channel)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py",
>   line 408, in revive
>       self.declare()   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py",
>   line 421, in declare
>       queue.declare()   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py",
>   line 608, in declare
>       self._create_queue(nowait=nowait, channel=channel)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py",
>   line 617, in _create_queue
>       self.queue_declare(nowait=nowait, passive=False, channel=channel)   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py",
>   line 652, in queue_declare
>       nowait=nowait,   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py",
>   line 531, in queue_declare
>       self._new_queue(queue, **kwargs)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 82, in _new_queue
>       self._get_or_create(queue)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 70, in _get_or_create
>       obj = self.session.query(self.queue_cls) \   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 65, in session
>       _, Session = self._open()   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 56, in _open
>       engine = self._engine_from_config()   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 51, in _engine_from_config
>       return create_engine(conninfo.hostname, **transport_options)   File
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/**init**.py",
>   line 386, in create_engine
>       return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2.5.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py",
>   line 144, in create
>       engineclass.**name**)) TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'visibility_timeout' sent to create_engine(), using configuration
>   MySQLDialect_mysqldb/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword
>   arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
>   [2019-05-11 12:00:57,898] {configuration.py:206} WARNING - section/key
>   [celery/celery_ssl_active] not found in config [2019-05-11
>   12:00:57,898] {default_celery.py:41} WARNING - Celery Executor will
>   run without SSL [2019-05-11 12:00:57,900] {**init**.py:45} INFO -
>   Using executor CeleryExecutor Starting flask [2019-05-11 12:00:58,083]
>   {_internal.py:122} INFO -  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8793/ (Press
>   CTRL+C to quit)

I am not worried about the `TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'visibility_timeout'` as of now as I am sure the configurations passed in airflow.conf is just getting picked up.

Let me know what I am missing, any help is highly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Can you see your Celery configuration in the web UI if `expose_config = True` in airflow.cfg?

Comment: Did you set up the AIRFLOW_HOME properly? Airflow picks the airflow.cfg from `AIRFLOW_HOME`, if airflow home is not setup it auto create an `airflow.cfg` files in the same directory where you lunch the `airflow worker` command.

Comment: I found the issue, in airflow.cfg I pushed the configurations along with `exector=LocalExecutor` but i forgot to check the `[celery]` part where the defaults were mentioned thus it was picking up.

Comment: Now the airflow worker/ airflow flower is running but the dags are not completed they are in running state for a long time.